# How to use capture operator in Elixir to capture a tuple from a list?

Tags: elixir

i am unable to understand that how to use capture operator to capture a tuple. Here is my code with function.

```
MyList.map([{"person 1",27},{"person 2",20}], fn({name,_}) -> name end)                 
// ["person 1","person 2"]
```

can anyone help me please on how to do it via capture operator. so far i have tried this but is no use.

```
MyList.map([{"person 1",27},{"person 2",20}], & &1}) // returns same List with same tuple
MyList.map([{"person 1",27},{"person 2",20}], &{&1,&2} &1) // error
```

Comment: you missing some `{` brackets in you second code section.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, i fixed it, but its still giving me error. Problem is with use of capture operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exact behaviour is impossible, one cannot reach to the inner state of captured terms, `&1`, `&2` etc capture *the whole parameter*. Use [`Kernel.elem/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#elem/2):

```rb
MyList.map([{"person 1",27},{"person 2",20}], & elem(&1, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you, i understand it now. :-)

Comment: i think i can use `MyList.map([{"person 1",27},{"person 2",20}], &elem(&1, 0))`
directly as well.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. Yes, this is exactly what I have suggested.